# The effect of HtmlWebpackPlugin on webpack dev server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using Webpack on a React project and it seems like [`HtmlWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) affects the [webpack dev server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) in a weird way that I don't understand.

It seems to allow me to browse to `index.html` no matter where that file is in the code base, something that is not possible using the dev server alone.

Let's say that I have the following directory structure:

```
myproj/
  |- package.json
  |- webpack.config.js
  |- src/
    |- index.html
    |- index.jsx
```

and a `webpack.config.js` file that looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
   
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname
    }
};
```

Then I run `webpack-dev-server --mode=development`. Since I have `devServer.contentBase` set to the current directory (`myproj`) and the `index.html` file is inside `myproj/src`, I must browse to `http://localhost:8080/src/index.html` to see my web app. If I try browsing `http://localhost:8080/index.html` then I get a 404. That makes sense to me.

Then I add the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, changing nothing else inside `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
....
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
    })
]
```

Now all of a sudden I can browse to http://localhost:8080/index.html just fine. In fact, I can hit either `http://localhost:8080/index.html` or `http://localhost:8080/src/index.html`.

What's up with that? What did `HtmlWebpackPlugin` do to make this possible?

Comment: it creates html file for you at `root`. Probably you have another  `index.html` inside `src`, which gets loaded on second case.

Comment: @Prajwal thanks for the info. So I guess like the bundle.js file, this index.html file only exists in memory? I don't see it being written to disk anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured this out.

#### TL;DR

Once you add `HtmlWebpackPlugin` you should remove this line from `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

and only browse to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`.

#### The Tedious Details:

Once you add in `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, it takes your `index.html` file and merges in a `<script>` tag that points to your webpack bundle. It serves this merged html file from `http://localhost:8080`. It does this even if `index.html` already contains a reference to the bundle.

The plugin doesn't actually overwrite `index.html` with the merged version. So browsing to `http://localhost:8080/src/index.html` just shows you that file as it is on disk.

So if your `src/index.html` file looks like this *before* you add `HtmlWebpackPlugin`:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">it worked</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

then *after* you add `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, browsing to `http://localhost:8080` gives you this merged version:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">it worked</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

So now you will have two references to the bundle, the one you added in the file and the one `HtmlWebpackPlugin` added.

Browsing to `http://localhost:8080/src` gives you what's on disk at `src/index.html`:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">it worked</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

However, since he whole point of using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` is to let it insert the bundle reference for you, that means you should remove that `<script>` tag from `src/index.html`. That in turn means that browsing to `src/index.html` won't work anymore because you no longer have a reference to your bundle!

You are now reliant on letting `HtmlWepbackPlugin` insert the `<script>` tag for you, which means that you must now browser to `http://localhost:8080/index.html` to get the version it generated.

Webpack. Be. Crazy.

Answer (score 3):

As you have observed, when you are running `webpack-dev-server`, all the webpack output files (including styles, scripts, and service workers), will be loaded from memory only. This will not write any files to configured output directory.

From [Webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server) docs,

> This modified bundle is served from memory at the relative path
>   specified in publicPath (see API). It will not be written to your
>   configured output directory. Where a bundle already exists at the same
>   URL path, the bundle in memory takes precedence (by default).

Answer (score 2):

you do have access to both http://localhost:8080/index.html and http://localhost:8080/src/index.html. But the are served differently.

For http://localhost:8080/src/index.html, it is served by webpack-dev-server just like when HtmlWebpackPlugin is not included. If you check the response content of this url, you will find that is is identical with the content of src/index.html on your disk.

For http://localhost:8080/index.html, it is served by HtmlWebpackPlugin from memory. If you check the response content of this url, you will find that all your bundle file are added to the HTML(that's why we use it). For the filename, you can config it to anything you like with the 'filename' field(you can specify a subdirectory too). check https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options for more detail.